# Xamarin.Forms - BLE any device connection lost

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

In the last project I use BLE plugin.

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>

    {
       myDeviceList.Add(a.Device);
    }

        await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
```

[image]

But right now I'm just looking for devices and adding what you find directly to this list.

I want this scan to work continuously and if any device gets lost, it can automatically delete it here.

BLE has StartScanningForDevicesAsync class but I don't know if this is useful for me.

```
 event EventHandler<DeviceErrorEventArgs> DeviceConnectionLost;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when a device has been disconnected. This occurs on intendet disconnects
        //     after Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IAdapter.DisconnectDeviceAsync(Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IDevice).
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please note - BLE scanning is very expensive procedure for the batteries. Guidelines recommends to start device scanning for little time intervals only (for example, in our app we use 15 sec). So I can advice you to scan your devices by timer, for example, 10 sec per minute (at least, you can start from these values and adjust them in future)

Comment: @Miamy Thanks for the advice, I'll take it. If I want to scan a minute or so, what kind of code should I use? To call the Scan function once every 30 seconds, await Task.Delay (30000); I used the command but this time the Scan function is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use something like this (pseudocode + C#):

```
StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            () =>
            {
                if (!isScanning)
                { 
                    new Handler().PostDelayed(StopScan, 10000); // stop 
                                      scanning after 10 sec
                    isScanning = true;
                    StartScan();
                }
               return true; // this result will tell to fire onTimer event again
           });
```

Here StartScan and StopScan - functions you use for communicating with BLE